# In C# does calling Dispose delete the object from Heap?

Tags: c#, dispose

If I do a conn.Dispose(); (where conn is an instance of a SqlConnection Class), will that clear the conn object from the heap?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, calling Dispose doesn't clear the connection from the heap. When you call the Dispose method on a SqlConnection instance all you do is return the connection to the underlying connection pool. It doesn't even close the connection. ADO.NET uses a connection pool. So when you create a new instance of SqlConnection you do not open a new connection, you simply draw a connection from the connection pool and when you call Dispose you simply return this connection to the connection pool so that it can be reused.

In general the `IDisposable` pattern in .NET is intended to be implemented by classes that hold some pointers to some unmanaged resources. Calling the Dispose method ensures that those unmanaged resources will be properly released.

Deleting an object from the heap is what the Garbage Collector does and when this happens is a non-deterministic event (you have no control over it).

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit please?

Comment: So what does it do? And how can I delete it (conn) off the heap?

Comment: Calling Dispose actually closes the SQL connection.

Comment: @ken2k, no, calling Dispose doesn't close the underlying connection. It only returns this connection to the ADO.NET connection pool.

Comment: @ken2k Why would you even want to do such a thing?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov: According to MSDN, yes, Dispose does close the connection ("Close and Dispose are functionally equivalent")
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.close.aspx

Comment: @ken2k, did you read the second `Note` in the documentation: `Login and logout events will not be raised on the server when a connection is fetched from or returned to the connection pool, because the connection is not actually closed when it is returned to the connection pool. For more information, see SQL Server Connection Pooling (ADO.NET).`?

Comment: @user1110437 You can't delete it, but you can (and should) break all ties(references) to it, at that point its not in your hand when the memory is actually freed and thats why we love(and hate) managed languages :)

Comment: @asawyer To what? Dispose a SqlConnection?

Comment: So could I say that Dispose() is a place where I do something that would need to be done once the object pointer is out of scope? Such as closing a handle to a file etc? If thats true, it would also mean that every .net class that implements IDisposable, will do something very specific for that class? You cannot generalize what is done in Dispose, right?

Comment: @ken2k I am sorry, I was not clear. What I should have asked was "Why do you think that you need to physically free the memory explicitly?" ALso I ment to ask user1110437, not you. Sorry! :)

Comment: @DarinDimitrov Yes, the connection still exists in the connection pool. But the fact is calling Dispose actually does what calling Close do. Which is closing the connection to the database (from the application POV).

Comment: @user1110437, I don't even understand what you are saying means. What you can say is that when you call the `.Dispose` method (and you should absolutely never do this manually because you should wrap your connection in a `using` statement) you are returning the connection to the ADO.NET connection pool.

Comment: @asawyer you don't need to do it explicitly. When you write
`using (SqlConnection myConn = new .....)`, you actually call Dispose.

Comment: @ken2k, how can a connection exist in the connection pool if the underlying database connection is closed? Opening and closing SQL connection is an expensive operation. That's why there's an ADO.NET connection pool. So that you don't have to open/close a database connection everytime you try to execute a SQL query. This could be disabled. You could specify in the connection string that you don't want to use a connection pool. This way when you call the Dispose method you will actually close the connection to the database.

Comment: Darin, Sorry for not being clear, my question is more geared towards understanding the use of Dispose. I used SQLConnection class, just for an example.

Comment: @user1110437, I tried to explain this in my answer: the dispose pattern is commonly used to deterministically release some resources that are hold by the class (often those are unmanaged resources). Do not confuse this with Garbage Collection. Garbage Collection is a non-deterministic event which cleans memory by removing unused objects.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov we're actually saying the same thing. The connection itself is not physically _closed_ because it still exists in the connection pool and will be used later. But a `Dispose` call the `Close` method, which _invalidates_ (can't find a better word) the connection for the application. Using a `SqlCommand` with an _invalidated_ connection won't work. Actually MSDN does not say _invalidates_ but _Close_. Different meanings, same word.

Comment: @ken2k I'm really late to the party, but just reading through these comments, whether the `Close()` method itself actually closes the connection to the database server or just releases it back to the connection pool is a configuration issue. The application code doesn't know, and shouldn't care. From the standpoint of the application, the connection is unusable until it has been "opened" again. But that too is an abstraction handled within the connection object. Again, the app doesn't know and shouldn't care. The *semantics* are `Open()` and `Close()`. The actual behavior is different.

Answer (score 1):

No. see [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.dispose.aspx)
The object still lives, until all references are gone.
A small example:

```
myObject = new Something();
myObject.Dispose()
myObject.Foo() // still perfectly valid (but pretty ugly)
myObject = null; // now the reference, while still living, could be collected.
GC.Collect(); // now it is quite sure gone. (never call it unless you have good reasons)
```

Answer (score 1):

No; that's the garbage collector's job.
You cannot explicitly interact with the heap at all.

Calling `Dispose()` closes expensive resources (in this case, a network connection) deterministically.

Answer (score 1):

No.

IDisposable provides a well known interface for the 'disposal' of objects.  Disposal is generally for the purpose of explicitly releasing resources that would otherwise be held until the object fell out of scope and was garbage collected, which is when an object is removed from memory (heap or stack, almost always heap).

Slightly off topic, you should also be aware that the `using` keyword works with `IDisposable` e.g.

```
using (var disposableObject = new DisposableObject())
{
   ..do stuff with disposableObject..
} //disposableObject.Dispose() implicitly called here.
```

Answer (score 1):

From msdn: [IDisposable.Dispose](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.dispose.aspx)

> Use this method to close or release unmanaged resources such as files, streams, and handles held by an instance of the class that implements this interface.

So, Dispose is about underlying resources that are outside the view of the garbage collector.  Dispose is not about the instance.

---

> will that clear the conn object from the heap?

The SqlConnection instance will Dispose its unmanaged connection resource (by returning it to the connection pool).  The SqlConnection instance does not "Dispose" itself from memory - it's a managed object and the Garbage Collector is responsible for that work.

Comment: David, When the destructor is called by GC, does the Dispose() get automatically called for classes that implement IDisposable?

Comment: No.  The finalizer does not automatically call Dispose.  It's also considered bad form for a finalizer to be written to call Dispose because you don't have control of when the GC will call that finalizer.  The best practice is to use the Using statement to ensure that Dispose gets called.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of IDisposable is to provide a standard means of notifying objects that they are no longer needed.  Some objects ask other entities (which may or may not even be on the same computer!) to do things on their behalf until further notice.  When an object is told that it is no longer needed, it can notify any entities that may be acting on its behalf that they no longer need to do so.

As a simple example, creating a file object may (indirectly) cause a request to be sent out to a file server to open a particular file for exclusive access.  Until the file server receives a request to close the file, it will not allow anyone else in the known universe to access it.  As long as the file object is needed, it will maintain exclusive access to the file.  If IDisposable.Dispose is called on the file object, it will (again, indirectly) cause a "close" request to be sent to the file server, thus allowing other programs and computers to access the file.

Note that if the file object were simply to disappear without notifying anyone that the previously-granted exclusive file access was no longer needed, the server might never let anyone else use the file.  To protect against this type of problem, the file object's class may define a Finalize() handler.  Any time the system creates an object of a class which overrides `Object.Finalize()`, the system will add it to a special list of objects with "registered" Finalize handlers.  If such an object is abandoned, the garbage-collector will run its Finalize method before it, or any objects to which it holds direct or indirect references, can actually be removed from memory.

Note that the purpose of Dispose is not to destroy the file object itself, but rather to allow it to notify the entity was providing exclusive access the file that such access is no longer needed.  Calling Dispose on an object whose class overrides `Object.Finalize()` will notify the garbage-collector that it no longer needs to worry about invoking the Finalize method before removing the object from memory, but won't otherwise destroy the object.